# R: How to manually set binned colour scale in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, scale

I'm trying to set a colour scale for a ggplot dotplot, demarking zones that are: unsuitable, suitable, ideal, suitable, unsuitable. Within your standard ggplot code wrapper, I have tried `gradient2`

```
scale_colour_gradient2(low = "grey",
                       mid = "red",
                       high = "grey",
                       midpoint = 25) +
```

[image: gradient2]

and `gradientn`;

```
scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(rainbow(5)),
                       breaks = seq(0, 30, by = 5),
                       limits = c(0, 30),
                       labels = as.character(seq(0, 30, by = 5))) +
```

[image: gradientn]

`stepsn`,

```
scale_colour_stepsn(colours = c("grey", "blue", "red", "blue", "grey"),
                    values = scales::rescale(c(0, 22, 25, 26, 29, 40))) +
```

[image: stepsn]

and `binned`

```
scale_colour_binned(type = "viridis",
                      breaks = c(22, 25, 26, 29),
                      limits = c(0, 40),
                      guide = guide_coloursteps(even.steps = FALSE,
                                                show.limits = TRUE)) +
```

[image: binned]

`binned` is the closest but I can't work out how to specify the 5 colours I want (i.e., not `viridis`). The help option for 'type' that I presumably want is:

> A function that returns a continuous colour scale

But I can't mentally square how/why I'd need to create a function that creates a continuous scale of colours, given I simply want to say (e.g.)

```
c("red", "yellow", "green", "yellow", "red")
```

I get the sense that either I'm close and am just misunderstanding a step somewhere (maybe multiple places), or I'm using the wrong approach, and it's none of these 3 functions.

Any chance anyone can advise?

Thanks all!

Edit: update following Will's suggestions: Leaving the values in the geom_point call untouched, i.e.

```
geom_point(aes(colour = MeanETemp24hU2M), size = 0.5) +
```

(rather than rescaling them to 0:1), the following code:

```
scale_colour_stepsn(colours = c("red", "yellow", "green", "yellow", "red"),
                      limits = c(0, 40),
                      guide = guide_coloursteps(even.steps = FALSE,
                                                show.limits = TRUE),
                      breaks = c(0, 22, 25, 26, 29, 40)) +
```

Produces:

[image: stepsn close]

Which is close but

A. the `colours` vector doesn't match the `breaks` bins

B. the colours themselves are blends rather than being the true R colours. Using a modification of Will's example:

```
x <- 1:100
y <- runif(100) * 100
tibble(x, y) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = x, y = y, color = y) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_stepsn(
    colours = c("red", "yellow", "green", "yellow", "red"),
    breaks = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1) * 100)
```

Produces:

[image: willexample]

The values are right and align to the colour bins properly (IDK why mine don't given the same formulation), but the colours are diluted blends - compare the red in that image to the red at the end of the rainbow in the second image.

Comment: If you're not necessarily wanting gradients between the colors, you might consider adding a column to your data frame that defines suitability in terms of unsuitable, suitable, ideal, and then coloring based on this factor?

Comment: lovely, elegant solution Will, nice one. Would still be conceptually interested in whether there's a proper solution along the lines of what I was trying, but I reckon I'll go with your solution when I get back to this tomorrow. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you were close for `scale_color_stepsn`, if you pass your rescale argument to breaks instead, it might work. I think the following does what you were hoping for?

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- 1:100
y <- runif(100)
tibble(x, y) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = x, y = y, color = y) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_stepsn(
    colours = c("red", "yellow", "green", "yellow", "red"),
    breaks = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1)
  )
```

Can replace `scale_color_gradientn`, which is much prettier!

```r
scale_color_gradientn(
    colours = c("red", "yellow", "green", "yellow", "red"),
    breaks = c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1)
```

EDIT:

The rescale issue is definitely causing a problem. I think this solution will work for `scales_color_gradientn`. Note I changed the test data frame up a little.

```r
library(tidyverse)

x <- seq(0, 40, 0.25)
y <- seq(0, 40, 0.25)
tibble(x, y) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  aes(x = x, y = y, color = y) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_gradientn(
    colours = c("red", "yellow", "green", "yellow", "red"),
    values = scales::rescale(c(0, 22, 25, 26, 29, 40))
  )
```

I tried several times to get something nice with `scales_color_stepsn`, but as you saw, this function seems to assign the "pure" colors at the breaks and merges the colors for values in between them (I wasn't able to understand some of the other unusual behavior with colors being out of order, etc., though). I think if you want a stepped gradient of pure red/yellow/green colors, my original comment is probably the best approach - assign a value in your data frame to map the colors to. The legend in the above code has evenly spaced labels, if you want to label the the breaks, add `breaks = c(0, 22, 25, 26, 29, 40)` to the arguments, although I found it difficult to read the labels that way. HTH.

Comment: Thanks again Will. No joy with the first code section as it stands - all dots come out green. Maybe I'm missing something but were you supposed to include rescale explicitly anywhere? [edit: not reqd for runif]. I tried rescaling breaks but it did nothing. Omitting 'values' is likely the cause of the legend disappearing too. gradientn looks close but the colours are the wrong way round (red in 'ideal' area) & is the same with your breaks or rescaled original values, which seems odd. I'm close with stepsn, but bizarrely the colours are in a weird order & I can't work out why (updated in Q)

Comment: Updated my answer with a different approach. HTH.

Answer (score 7):

I was trying to do exactly that, and found a way with `binned_scale`, which is what `scale_color_stepsn` calls. I will use a similar example as Will and I hope you can translate that to your case.

The `palette` argument still needs to be a function but you can use one that simply returns the colors that you want. Here I show that you can use irregular breaks, and specify the limits separately if you want to use `show.limits = TRUE` (otherwise it shows the limits in your dataset).

```
x <- 1:100
y <- runif(100) * 100
tib <- tibble(x, y)

ggplot(tib, aes(x = x, y = y, color = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  binned_scale(aesthetics = "color",
               scale_name = "stepsn", 
               palette = function(x) c("red", "yellow", "green", "yellow", "red"),
               breaks = c(5, 10, 25, 60),
               limits = c(0, 100),
               show.limits = TRUE, 
               guide = "colorsteps"
  )
```

Here, `guide = "colorsteps"` was needed to have filled squares in the legend. If you want proportional bars in the legend as with `even.steps = FALSE`, then you need to should use `guide = "colorbar"` instead.

[image: binned_scale_example]

Comment: Good stuff @Goine0! I noticed you used 4 breaks + the 2 limits, vs my 6 breaks... I wonder if this is what keeps your colours from blending like mine have? I'll try to test this when I'm next back at my main machine. Cheers!

Comment: No, the colors are assigned differently because of the palette. TBH, this is sort of a hack and I don't think it was intended for such a use. The 6 breaks didn't work as intended with `show.limits = TRUE` so that's why I had to specify the limits separately. The whole thing is a bit verbose, but manages to do exactly what you want.